# order multiple tables according to one column

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible, using SQL to pull data from different tables, then sort the data according to one column that is in all tables. eg, I have 3 tables. Base, Selects, Sub. They all 3 have a position column,

```
Select base_layers.position, selects.position, subbases.position 
from base_layers,selects,subbases 
Order By (alls)position;
```

That is exactly what I actually want to do... But have a feeling it is not possible.

Comment: have you relations between those 3 tables ? if yes show them or show your tables structures

Comment: I don't have relations between them, but they all have the same parent, if that counts for anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a union:

(I'm assuming you don't want to cross join all 3 tables)

```
select Position
from
(
  select base_layers.position AS Position
  from base_layers

  union

  select selects.position
  from selects

  union

  select subbases.position
  from subbases 
) x
order by Position ASC;
```

Comment: @StuartLC Hi thank you very much, it seems to be working quite well, May I just ask how I could display more data from the tables without stuffing my union up?

Comment: You can add more columns as long is all unions have the same number of columns and the column types are compatable.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax was incorrect. Try this version.

```
SELECT * FROM

(

    SELECT base_layers.position
    FROM base_layers

  UNION ALL

    SELECT selects.position 
    FROM selects 

  UNION ALL

    SELECT subbases.position 
    FROM subbases 

) tbl ORDER BY tbl.position;
```